# Python Directed Graph Edges List -Find All Ancestors and Children

Tags: python, list, data-structures, graph, relation

I have the following list of directed graph edges:

`edges = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6], [4,6]]`

I want all the children (including the connecting nodes) and all the ancestors (including the connecting nodes) of node 4 in the form of a Python list as well.

```
ancestors = [1, 2, 3]

children = [5, 6]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please share yours attempts to see where we can help you

Comment: Same Que: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456092/python-directed-graph-edges-list-find-all-ancestors-and-children

Comment: @Rakesh Link is invalid